# Position of tree after node expansion

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, tree

I recently took up D3 for a project, and i am facing an issue with the tree layout. When i initially load the tree layout it stays nicely within the SVG, as seen on the screenshot below. [image: Initial state of tree when no nodes are opened]

However, once i start opening the nodes, the more nodes i open, the more start going up and thus become invisible, as seen on the images below.

When i start opening nodes:
[image: When i start opening nodes]
When all nodes are opened:
[image: All of the nodes are opened.]

As you can see i have made the svg scrollable vertically so that i can see bigger trees.

Here is how i create the tree layout:

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
         .nodeSize([55,30]);
```

Right now I found a solution by increasing the height of the 'g' element which holds all the nodes every time i click on a node that has children, but it is not a good solution because this causes the whole tree to "jump" every time this happens.

```
//creates the <g> element
var gWidth = 90;
var gHeight = 250;   
var vis = svg.append("g")
            .attr('id', 'group')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + gWidth + "," + gHeight + ")");


function updateSvg(node){
 //moves the g element 50px down on each click that has a child
                  if(node.children){
                    gHeight +=50;
                    vis.attr("transform", "translate(" + gWidth + "," + gHeight + ")");
                   }
                   else{
                    gHeight-=50;
                    vis.attr("transform", "translate(" + gWidth + "," + gHeight + ")");
                  // }

}
```

I am also increasing the SVG height if there are more than a certain amount of nodes, but i think this is out of scope for my current issue.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: just check if the nodes go offscreen (< 0 || > height) and zoom svg accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two ways of trying to solve this:

**1. Scroll your container** automatically to avoid the jump, in your solution with the `gHeight` variable:

```
  document.getElementById("container").scrollTop += 50;
```

I am really not sure of this, though, so I think you'll do better with:

**2. Use d3 zoom & pan methods** The zoom behavior works pretty well, see

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior

It boils down to

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom();
svg.call(zoom);
```

and so you can get rid of the scrollbars and `gHeight`s, and basically don't have to worry anymore about the window boundaries.